# Funcion no definida

Tags: php

estoy creando un formulario en el cual he generado una funcion que lo que hace es comprobar que solamente en el campo usuario se escriba "cadena de texto", cual es el problema? Que me dice que no esta definida, la funcion la tengo en otro archvio diferente a donde tengo la "comprobacion" del formulario. Voy un poco perdido en funciones, asi que seguramente no este bien.

### Archivo de la funcion

```
 <?php


    function UsuarioValidado($user){
        
        return preg_match('/[a-z]/i',  $user);
    }
        
?>
```

---

Archivo de comprobacion

---

```
     <?php 

   if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
      if(isset($_POST['usuarioname'], $_POST['contraseña'])) {
         if(empty($user && $password)) {
            $user = trim($_POST['usuarioname']);
            $password = trim($_POST['contraseña']);
            if($user != '' && $password != '') {   
               **if(UsuarioValidado($user)) {**       
                  if(($user == "admin") && ($password == "123456")) {
                     session_start();
                     $_SESSION["usuario"] = $user;
                     header("Location: paneladministracion.php");
                  }
                  else {
                     echo ("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos");
                  }
               }
               else {
                  echo("Solo se admiten caracteres [A-Z]");
               }
            }
            else {
               echo ("Porfavor rellene los campos");
            }
         }
         else {
            echo ("Faltan parámetros en la petición de login.");
         }
      }
   }

   
   require_once("functions.php");
   


?>
```

........................

Comment: Creo que le hace falta un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta. Pero así por encima, no veo dónde invoques el archivo donde está tu función, así que tiene lógica que PHP te diga eso.

Comment: Pon el require_once antes de el resto del código

Comment: Acabo de actualizarlo, si se sigue sin entender digamelo. Gracias

Comment: Ya esta, solucionado muchas gracias!

Comment: Debes incluir el archivo antes de tratar de acceder a la función. Coloca esta línea `require_once("functions.php");` al inicio del archivo y ya debe funcionar sin problema.